# Faster way to search for whole words

Tags: search

I can search for whole words like this

```
/\<search term\>
```

`\<` and `\>` match left and right word boundaries respectively.

But how can I insert those automatically? They are awkward to type out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to add a commandline-mode mapping with `:cmap` to add `\<` and `\>`; so then you'd type `hello`, press e.g. `<F1>`, and that will transform it to `\<hello\>`.

A simple version might look like:

```
cnoremap <expr> <F1> index(['/', '?'], getcmdtype()) is -1 ? "\<F1>" : "\<Home>\\<\<End>\\>"
```

It just sends `<Home>\<<End>\>`. This is a bit naïve since it doesn't check whether there already are angled brackets, and it frobs with the cursor position. A better, but longer, version might look like:

```
fun! s:wrap()
    let l = getcmdline()
    let pos = getcmdpos()

    " Remove
    if l[:1] is '\<' && l[-2:] is '\>'
        call setcmdpos(pos - 2)
        return l[2:len(l)-3]
    endif

    " Add
    if l[:1] isnot '\<'
        let l = '\<' . l
        let pos += 2
    endif
    if l[-2:] isnot '\>'
        let l .= '\>'
    endif
    call setcmdpos(pos)
    return l
endfun

cnoremap <expr> <F1> index(['/', '?'], getcmdtype()) is -1 ? "\<F1>" : "\<C-\>e<SID>wrap()\<CR>"
```

With `<C-\>e` the return value of a function is inserted, the function removes `\<` and `\>` if they exist, or adds them if they don't. If also preserves the cursor position.

Answer (score 12):

There are two different ways to do this.

1. You can insert those *and* the word currently under your cursor with `*`. So for example, if your cursor is on "hello", and you press asterisk, vim will treat that the same as `/\<hello\><cr>`. This is generally going to be the fastest way ([more info](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13690/2920)). However, there's one downside. If you don't have the word you want to search for in your buffer, then you can't really navigate to that word and press `*`. And doing something like `iHello<esc>*u` isn't really that much better than just `/\<Hello\>`. So this is only more efficient when you are near that word. If that happens a lot, you could try method 2:
2. Create a mapping. Since we don't want to overwrite `/`, this is the perfect use case for `<leader>`. I personally would do this (put in `.vimrc`):

   ```
   nnoremap <leader>/ /\<\><left><left>
   ```

   which will insert the brackets *and* position your cursor between them so you can type out the word you want to search.